# Specify which controllers to exclude from before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, before-filter

I'm using devise for authentication and have some before_filters in my application controller. Issue I'm seeing is that when I try to logout the before_filter intercepts that and keeps me on the view that's I've setup in the before_filter. Is there any way for me to specify which controllers should be excluded from the application controller or some other file?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can qualify a filter with `:only` or `:except`.

```
before_filter :filter_name, :except => [:action1, :action2]
```

Or if the filter (as I now see is the case in your situation) is defined in `ApplicationController` and you want to bypass it in a subclass controller, you can use a `skip_before_filter` with the same qualifications in the subclass controller:

```
skip_before_filter :filter_name, :except => [:action1, :action2]
```

Answer (score 104):

In the controller where you want to skip a before filter specified in an inherited controller, you can tell rails to skip the filter

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Comment: This presents an answer to the original question in a more clear mannor, however `skip_before_filter :filter-name, :except => [:action1, :action2]` from the accepted answer is a great tip!

Comment: @Jesse Wolgamott what if the controller where I want to skip the before filter lives in a gem? Is there a way to specify on the before_filter itself something more than just actions?

Comment: @hunteros - you'd probably need to re-open the class in your code, and add the skip filter then

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that, but figured that would be the only solution. Are there conventions for where in the code base I should re-open the controller class?

Answer (score 12):

In config/application.rb

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Referenced by:

[How to skip a before_filter for Devise's SessionsController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209663/how-to-skip-a-before-filter-for-devises-sessionscontroller)

Answer (score 3):

Answers above are good except:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: skip_before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use skip_before_action instead.`

So please use `before_action` and `skip_before_action` instead of `*-filter`.