# How to skip a before_filter for Devise's SessionsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, before-filter

I have a `before_filter` in my `ApplicationController`; that is, for every controller in my project.

How can I `skip_before_filter` for Devise's `SessionsController` create action ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We did something like this:

First up, create your own session controller, make sure to inherit correctly:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :foobar
```

Then fix the routes

```
devise_for :users,
  :controllers => {
    :sessions => "sessions"
  }
```

Alternatively you could monkey-patch Devise's session controller.

Comment: This sounds like a nice way to do it, but i can't get it to work :/

Comment: I found this solution "cleaner" than the more upvote one. It keeps the controller logic in controllers.

Answer (score 65):

Here's a method my colleague just showed me:

```
# In config/application.rb
module YourAppNameHere
  class Application < Rails::Application
  # Whatever else is already here...

    # The part to add
    config.to_prepare do
      Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_filter :your_before_filter_here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, and I couldn't get the accepted answer to work at all. So +1 - thanks!

Comment: I also had trouble with the accepted answer.  I tried this and it worked, but my application was noticeably slower (maybe ~ 1 second added moving from page to page).

Comment: @John - I'm not sure why a `to_prepare` block would be so slow for you, but FYI, according to the Rails guides, such blocks "will run upon every request in development, but only once (during boot-up) in production and test."

Comment: I was using the [devise\_token\_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem, I only had to replace `Devise::SessionsController` with `DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController` and it worked brilliantly!

Comment: Also I would like to mention that you have to add all Devise controller you want to skip, like Devise::PasswordsController, Devise::RegistrationsController

Comment: @NathanLong thank you - i only want to skip the new action in the session controller - how would your answer change to reflect this additional requirement?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I wrote my answer 5 years ago - I don't remember the context anymore. :) Maybe try asking a new question?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon you can use `Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_filter :check_toc, only: [:new]`

Answer (score 25):

I recently had this problem with filter in my `application_controller` I solved it using `skip_before_filter`

Rails < 4

```
skip_before_filter :check_subdomain!, if: :devise_controller?
```

Rails >= 4

```
skip_before_action :check_subdomain!, if: :devise_controller?
```

Comment: skip_before_action :check_subdomain!, if: :devise_controller?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way in lib/devise_sessions_controller_decorator.rb:

```
module DeviseSessionsControllerDecorator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    skip_before_filter :your_filter_name
  end
end

Devise::SessionsController.send(:include, DeviseSessionsControllerDecorator)
```

Because classes are not cached in development mode, you may need to add something like this to config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.send(:include, DeviseSessionsControllerDecorator)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Before my colleague showed me the way I posted in my other answer, I did this. I'm posting this in case you think it's simpler.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  before_filter :do_something

  def do_something
    unless params[:controller] == 'devise/sessions'
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check in your filter method whether it is devise controller or not.

```
  if params[:controller] != 'devise/sessions'
```

Answer (score 0):

### new answer

what about wrapping the before_filter in an unless block filtering by `params[:controller]`

```
def some_before_action
  unless params[:controller] == "sessions_controller_for_devise_name"
      ... #=> do the stuff here
  end 
end
```

### old answer

just authorize which actions should use the before filter

```
before_filter :action, :only => ...
```

and authorize your others.

[found this here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)

Comment: i know about that, but in order to work like this, you need to put it in the sessions controller. That is the devise gem's controller. Which is definitely not a good idea :/

Comment: can you use the :only => to filter the ones you want?

Comment: editted the answer, does that maybe work? using params[:controller] if it is available in the application controller