# Skip before filter with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, before-filter, activeadmin

I am using devise and recently added active admin, which created a separate table of admin_users to keep admins.

All works fine with Active Admin when I try to log in and browse around. However, my application controller has this for general users:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
```

Because of this, when inside the active admin interface, whenever I try to edit or delete anything, it asks me to log in. I learned that a skip_before_filter can be used inside the controller in which  the before_filter needs to be excluded, however Active Admin doesn't have a controller file in the controllers folder or anywhere in my project I could look.

can anyone suggest how to make active admin ignore the application beofre_filter which I want to apply on all of the client/user facing?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` you can add the following:

```
config.skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

You can also use the DSL provided to modify the ActiveAdmin controller: http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modify_the_controller

Note: For Rails versions before 5.0 you will want to use `skip_before_filter`.

Comment: For some reason, the line in the initializers file is not working for me.  And I am not sure. . in which files do you add the code to modify  the ActiveAdmin controller?

Comment: @John Make sure you restart your app after changing any initializer, and you can use the controller-modifying DSL inside the admin definition files (i.e. app/admin/post.rb).

Comment: @coreyward, couldn't get it to work, posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903176/cant-get-skip-before-filter-to-work-with-activeadmin-in-rails

Comment: Looks like it wasn't related to ActiveAdmin so much as Devise. Glad you got it figured out. :)

Comment: I'm trying to call `config.skip_after_filter` but am getting: `undefined method 'skip_after_filter' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x007fa445d5c898`

Comment: For me also, adding skip before filter not working and restarted also. am using the rails 3.2.14 and activeadmin gem.

Comment: But doing below, have turn off the authentication, `config.authentication_method = false
config.current_user_method   = false
`

Comment: Worked for me! rails v -5.2.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get @coreyward's solution to work, but editing `config/application.rb` as per [this Devise post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6738208/720054) and adding:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
    controller do
      skip_before_action :name_of_filter_to_skip
    end

    # Other code
end
```

to `admin/dashboard.rb` did the trick. It didn't work by just editing `config/application.rb` alone. Make sure to restart your server!

Comment: the documentation says that the config step adds the configuration to all of your RESOURCE controllers, so the dashboard is apparently excepted from that list... going directly to /admin/some_resouce still skips things for me... so you are right, this is needed in addition to coreyward's solution

Answer (score 3):

both of the corey and Sooie are right... but only partially, to stop your blanket authorize_user! filter from affecting active_admin you need to implement both of their answers...

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
config.skip_before_filter :authorize_user!
```

app/admin/dashboard.rb

```
controller do
  skip_before_filter :authorize_user!
end
```

Comment: Why should you implement both?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make the solutions of @fringd and @coreyward to work on Rails4 (using ActiveAdmin master branch).

So, I've moved the filter methods (I have two filters: `authorize_user!` and `check_user_status`) to a new Concern, and included this created module into the Controllers which had those filters (**except for the `ApplicationController`**, which should remain clean).

Then restarted the server, and problem solved.

Comment: Can you please add code to those concern you described