# Can't get skip_before_filter to work with ActiveAdmin in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, before-filter

I am using the devise gem for authentication and have the following before_filter in my ApplicationController:

```
  before_filter :require_login

  def require_login
    unless user_signed_in? || params[:controller] == 'devise/sessions'
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access that page."
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
```

I have recently implemented the ActiveAdmin gem and am trying to get skip_before_filter to work for ActiveAdmin, so that I can access ActiveAdmin.  I have attempted the methods outlined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591310/skip-before-filter-with-active-admin/7591335#comment11134794_7591335), adding the following to config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
  config.skip_before_filter :require_login
```

and also adding the following to one of my admin model files, listing.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Listing do

  controller do
    skip_before_filter :require_login
  end

end
```

but it doesn't seem to work, even after restarting the server and browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things:

First: I think you're using Devise inefficiently. Instead of a custom login method on application_controller, you should:

```
class ApplicationController 
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

That's it -- everything else works.

Second: Active Admin uses a different user class -- the "admin_user" (rather than "user"). By default, you'll use the following credentials:

```
email: admin@example.com 
password: password
```

Comment: Using the devise authenticate_user! method got rid of my problems.  Thanks!