# is there any way to skip authentication in custom_active admin actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, pandastream

So, I have a collection_action in [active admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) that is used by [PandaStream api](http://www.pandastream.com) to send back notifications when video is processed:

```
  collection_action :notify, :method => :post do
    # some irrelevant to the question code
  end
```

**rake routes returns:**

```
notify_admin_videos POST       /admin/videos/notify(.:format)            admin/videos#notify
```

The problem is when I got notification from pandastream, I get:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

That's expected as the [panda api](http://www.pandastream.com) is not authenticated in my admin panel. So question is, is there any way to skip authentication in custom_active admin actions?

Please help clear this up for me!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skip before filter with Active Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591310/skip-before-filter-with-active-admin)

Comment: definitely not a duplicate, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain methods are delegated from the admin register to the controller, as shown here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/4f445b51c22b12af2cdde57fe2ce9835c32ef88e/lib/active_admin/resource_dsl.rb#L156

So you should be able to do something like below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Video do
  skip_before_action :authenticate_admin_user!, only: :notify
end
```