# before_filter :except a devise action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, before-filter

Every new user must accept the EULA in order to use the service provided by my RoR application, so when the user first time logs in to my website, s/he has to accept the EULA, if s/he does NOT want to accept, s/he can just logout, so:

I have a `before_filter` in my `ApplicationController` with an `:except` action:

```
before_filter :check_eula, :except => [:destroy]
```

And there is link on my EULA page:

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => link_class) %>
```

And I'm using Devise:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out                   {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

The problem is that, it seems the `:check_eula` is still called when the user clicks the "Logout" link without accepting the EULA.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the following is working, but here is the solution:

In `config/application.rb`:

```
config.to_prepare do
  # ...

  Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_filter :check_eula, :only => [:destroy]
end
```

Reference:

[How to skip a before_filter for Devise's SessionsController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209663/how-to-skip-a-before-filter-for-devises-sessionscontroller)