# Before filter assign exception for entire controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, before-filter

Every one of my `Users` has a `has_many` relation with `Character`. Now before they can use the application i need them to first select one Character as their main thus I want to keep redirecting them to `members` controller show method until they select the main character.

My approach works however there is a problem when someone for instance wants to logout before selecting a main character it keeps redirecting them to `member_path`. How do i add `devise` controller to exception to this rule and my entire `members` controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

    before_filter :check_for_main
    skip_before_filter :check_for_main, :only => [:members => :show, :users => :sign_out]

    # Check if user has a main character selected
    private
    def check_for_main

        # Check signed in user
        if user_signed_in?

            # Check associated characters if any are set as main
            redirect_to member_path(current_user.id), :alert => "Please select your main character."
            unless current_user.characters.any?(&:main)

            end
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not want to pollute my code by adding another controller to subclass Devise controller just for that one line: `skip_before_filter`. My first attempt was to add `skip_before_filter` to devise controller its self but you should really avoid that.

Anyhow running `rake routes` shows that devise controllers are actually named `devise/controller_name` always with the `devise/ prefix` before the name. Since i was not going to extend devise controllers further only thing that made sense was to add a conditional statement to the method it self to skip requests from devise package.

For all my other controllers i followed `@Stuart M` advice.

My new code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

    before_filter :check_for_main

    # Check if user has a main character selected
    private
    def check_for_main

        # Check signed in user
        if user_signed_in?

            if not params[:controller].to_s.include? "devise"
                # Check associated characters if any are set as main
                if not current_user.characters.any?(&:main)
                    redirect_to member_path(current_user.id), :alert => "Please select your main character."
                end
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

In both your `MembersController` and `UsersController` you should have `skip_before_filter :check_for_main` with the `:only` option specifying which action(s) in those controllers for which the filter should be skipped. You currently have

```
skip_before_filter :check_for_main, :only => [:members => :show, :users => :sign_out]
```

But that should instead be

```
# in MembersController
skip_before_filter :check_for_main, :only => [:show]

# in UsersController
skip_before_filter :check_for_main, :only => [:sign_out]
```

Comment: I know that my problem however is that i don't have the users controller.

Comment: What controller is the `:sign_out` action a part of?

Comment: Its part of devise controller that i cant access.

Comment: You should be able to subclass the Devise controller and customize it. See this question's top answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209663/how-to-skip-a-before-filter-for-devises-sessionscontroller

Comment: Also, the **Configuring Controllers** section of Devise's [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: It's pointless to subclass Devise controller just for this I have members controller that will handle my members. I don't have the users controller that what devise created.

Comment: Could you combine them? Just set the Devise controller subclass to your existing MembersController, and have that handle both functions. As long as you set up your routes properly and none of the action names overlap you could consolidate the two controllers into one.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Does Devise controller extend ApplicationController how it is even named ?