# How to skip before_filter :authenticate_user! if current_admin_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, activeadmin

Is there a simple way to skip the devise `before_filter :authenticate_user!` for a model if I'm signed into active admin and I'm therefore `current_admin_user`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209663/how-to-skip-a-before-filter-for-devises-sessionscontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try that?

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, unless: :current_admin_user
```

That should not run the before_filter if the variable :current_admin_user is true.

Comment: Wow, I knew I was missing the obvious answer. Thanks!