# Routing with Devise confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have implemented Devise confirmable which is working properly.  When a user signs up for the first time they get:

- Re-directed to the application root at localhost:3000/en
- Flash notice saying "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account."

So far so good.

I then updated the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Newly signed up users then find themselves redirected to localhost:3000/en/users/sign_in, with the confusing message "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

I've been browsing the Devise [how to's](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) but haven't yet cracked it.  What is the simplest way to fix this problem?

**Update**

Here is more detail of the Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery                                  
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :set_i18n_locale_from_params

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "Access denied!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  protected

  def set_i18n_locale_from_params
        ...
  end
end
```

**Update**

Here is the log as requested.

```
Started POST "/en/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-05 17:28:37 +0100
[17:28:37] Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
[17:28:37]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xUGLBMvZVWrtqLWpnAsa7R361QaGrOz/aVfEwvlS6xY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"...@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "locale"=>"en"}
[17:28:37]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
[17:28:37]   User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = '...@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
[17:28:37]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = 'a2XPMojypDn6uzzVAqcs' LIMIT 1
[17:28:37]   SQL (16.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "failed_attempts", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "locale", "locked_at", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "role", "sign_in_count", "unconfirmed_email", "unlock_token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21) RETURNING "id"  [["confirmation_sent_at", Fri, 05 Oct 2012 16:28:38 UTC +00:00], ["confirmation_token", "a2XPMojypDn6uzzVAqcs"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 05 Oct 2012 16:28:38 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "...@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$HnsOCZgVTaEg9bniVzBe7OKIvw4x5hdAqjwrCG14eQDCvSTz8mxdu"], ["failed_attempts", 0], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["locale", nil], ["locked_at", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["role", 0], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["unconfirmed_email", nil], ["unlock_token", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 05 Oct 2012 16:28:38 UTC +00:00]]
[17:28:37]   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.8ms)
[17:28:37] 
Sent mail to ...
[17:28:37]    (0.8ms)  COMMIT
[17:28:37] Redirected to http://localhost:3000/en
[17:28:37] Completed 302 Found in 5050ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[17:28:42] 

Started GET "/en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-05 17:28:42 +0100
[17:28:42] Processing by PageController#index as HTML
[17:28:42]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
[17:28:42] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
[17:28:42] 

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-05 17:28:42 +0100
[17:28:42] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
[17:28:42]   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.9ms)
[17:28:42]   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.8ms)
[17:28:42] Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 20.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In routes.rb I have:

```
root :to => "page#index"
```

So what's happening is that PageController#index is redirecting the user to sign in.  So the question boils down to how to exempt only this from :authenticate_user! in the Application Controller.

**Resolution**

So thanks to jibiel and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011764/specify-which-controllers-to-exclude-from-before-filter) the answer is:

```
  class PageController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
  end
```

Simples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :unless => :devise_controller?
```

And `devise` [will handle](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L2) authentications on its controller actions by himself. Otherwise you're overriding them as they're *prepended* to your `before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm afraid this didn't work.  It behaves in exactly the same way.  I tried re-starting the server and moving the line to the very top of the Application Controller.  I've put more details in the question in case this helps.

Comment: Then please provide log from penult action. I think it's something like Started POST "/users" ... Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML. Need to know where exactly authentication fails. Is it only redirection that bothers you? Was user properly created in the case?

Comment: This is helpful.  I've posted the log which shows the controller action to exempt from :authenticate_user!

Comment: You got me there.  I've posted the solution.  Much appreciated.