# Rails: After devise user_signed_in? have a sitewide validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise

As a better alternative to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613825/rails-redirect-to-for-default-application-layout I need to validate with user interaction before other web site features become available.

Something like "**when** user_signed_in? yield to controllers and views if **account_verified?** otherwise redirect_to **verify_account**"

I'm guessing this would look like a before_action in ApplicationController... I'm going to try and hash it out.  I'll post my answer here when I get it.

**EDIT**: I'm not verifying the devise login.  That's already done.  This is something totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves it for me.  [Specify which controllers to exclude from before_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011764/specify-which-controllers-to-exclude-from-before-filter)

Also for my before_filter I needed to move the methods into a module in my lib folder since I was getting a Controller not initialized error.  The error was from a self.mymethod within the controller being called as MyController.mymethod  This doesn't work, hence moving it all into the lib folder inside a module.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with devises authenticate_user!

So in your application_controller.rb

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Which redirects to sign in if they aren't logged in

Comment: I need my own authenticate method.  It needs to run on all controllers except the verification one and unless the user is not signed in.