# Run before filter an large number of actions in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, applicationcontroller

I have lots of controller in my Rails application, and I need to use a `before_filter` before some actions in different controllers. The before filter will execute the same code of all these actions. Is there a clean DRY way(in `application_controller` for instance) to specify the list of actions that should run this `before_filter`? I have tried to use `before_filer` in all controllers(9), but this looks so repetitive since it is the same code.

Comment: Did you check this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011764/specify-which-controllers-to-exclude-from-before-filter

Comment: thnks but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

why not `ApplicationController` ? If you define any `before_filter` in application controller then it is going to be executed on each request.

Now you are saying it looks repetitive but it actually don't. mentioning `before_filter` in `application_controller.rb` actually represents DRY AKA you don't have to specify that `before_filter` anywhere else.

Of course not all of the 9 controllers are going to get execute at the same time so `ApplicationController` is a preferred way

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_filter :pre_execute_action
  ...
end
class MyController < ApplicationController
  ...
  skip_before_filter :pre_execute_action, except: [:methods_for_which_it_should_execute]
  ...
end
```

try above code as a reference

Comment: the problem is that if I put it in application_controller it will be execute before ALL action. and I want it to be execute only for about 20% of the actions not ALL of them. I have about 70 actions and I want the before_filter to be executed before only 12 actions

Comment: so for that you can have `skip_before_filter :method_defined_in_application_controller except: [:methods_for_which_it_should_execute]` now it will run for only those 20% of actions. you have to define this in the controllers where you need it to execute for certain methods